# How to mock and test a method that wraps a module function using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have written a function that uses the `pushover-notifications` module to send notifications via Pushover. It looks like follows:

```
const Push = require('pushover-notifications')

const sendPushoverNotification = (message) => {
    const p = new Push({
        user: process.env.PUSHOVER_USER_KEY,
        token: process.env.PUSHOVER_AUTH_TOKEN,
        onerror: (error) => {} // Needs to be specified since this error cannot be caught in the p.send block.
    })

    const msg = {
        // These values correspond to the parameters for msg are detailed on https://pushover.net/api
        // 'message' is required. All other values are optional.
        message,    // Required.
        title: 'Title',
        sound: 'pushover',
        priority: 1
    }

    p.send(msg, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('[Pushover] An error occurred.')
            console.error(error)
        }

        if (JSON.parse(result).status === 1) { // Status 1 means push was sent successfully.
            console.log('[Pushover] Push notification sent.')
        } else {
            console.error('[Pushover] An error occurred.')
            console.error(result)
        }
    })
}

module.exports = sendPushoverNotification
```

I want to mock `p.send(msg, (error, result)` such that the code block below it is triggered which either logs `[Pushover] An error occurred.` or `[Pushover] Push notification sent.`.

In a file called `tests/__mocks__/pushover-notifications.js` to mock the module with the following code, I have:

```
function Pushover() {

}

Pushover.prototype.send = () => {
    console.log('Message sent')
}

module.exports = {
    Pushover
}
```

Under `tests/send-pushover-notification.test.js`:

```
const sendPushoverNotification = require('../../src/send-pushover-notification')

test('Should send Pushover message', () => {
    sendPushoverNotification('message')
})
```

The error I am getting is from the first block of code that I posted:

```
TypeError: Push is not a constructor

  2 | 
  3 | const sendPushoverNotification = (message) => {
> 4 |     const p = new Push({
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) mock the `pushover-notifications` module.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const Push = require('pushover-notifications');

const sendPushoverNotification = (message) => {
  const p = new Push({
    user: process.env.PUSHOVER_USER_KEY,
    token: process.env.PUSHOVER_AUTH_TOKEN,
    onerror: (error) => {},
  });

  const msg = {
    message,
    title: 'Title',
    sound: 'pushover',
    priority: 1,
  };

  p.send(msg, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('[Pushover] An error occurred.');
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }

    if (JSON.parse(result).status === 1) {
      console.log('[Pushover] Push notification sent.');
    } else {
      console.error('[Pushover] An error occurred.');
      console.error(result);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = sendPushoverNotification;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sendPushoverNotification = require('.');
const Push = require('pushover-notifications');

jest.mock(
  'pushover-notifications',
  () => {
    const mPush = { send: jest.fn() };
    return jest.fn(() => mPush);
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('59942177', () => {
  it('should send notification', () => {
    const p = new Push();
    const mResult = JSON.stringify({ status: 1 });
    p.send.mockImplementationOnce((msg, callback) => {
      callback(null, mResult);
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    sendPushoverNotification('message');
    expect(Push).toBeCalledWith({ user: undefined, token: undefined, onerror: expect.any(Function) });
    expect(p.send).toBeCalledWith(
      { message: 'message', title: 'Title', sound: 'pushover', priority: 1 },
      expect.any(Function),
    );
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('[Pushover] Push notification sent.');
  });

  it('should handle error if status is not equal 1', () => {
    const p = new Push();
    const mResult = JSON.stringify({ status: 2 });
    p.send.mockImplementationOnce((msg, callback) => {
      callback(null, mResult);
    });
    const errorLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
    sendPushoverNotification('message');
    expect(Push).toBeCalledWith({ user: undefined, token: undefined, onerror: expect.any(Function) });
    expect(p.send).toBeCalledWith(
      { message: 'message', title: 'Title', sound: 'pushover', priority: 1 },
      expect.any(Function),
    );
    expect(errorLogSpy).toBeCalledWith('[Pushover] An error occurred.');
    expect(errorLogSpy).toBeCalledWith(mResult);
  });

  it('should handle error if push failure', () => {
    const p = new Push();
    const mError = new Error('network error');
    p.send.mockImplementationOnce((msg, callback) => {
      callback(mError);
    });
    const errorLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
    sendPushoverNotification('message');
    expect(Push).toBeCalledWith({ user: undefined, token: undefined, onerror: expect.any(Function) });
    expect(p.send).toBeCalledWith(
      { message: 'message', title: 'Title', sound: 'pushover', priority: 1 },
      expect.any(Function),
    );
    expect(errorLogSpy).toBeCalledWith('[Pushover] An error occurred.');
    expect(errorLogSpy).toBeCalledWith(mError);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59942177/index.test.js
  59942177
    ✓ should send notification (16ms)
    ✓ should handle error if status is not equal 1 (2ms)
    ✓ should handle error if push failure (5ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    [Pushover] Push notification sent.

  console.error node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    [Pushover] An error occurred.

  console.error node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    {"status":2}

  console.error node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    [Pushover] An error occurred.

  console.error node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Error: network error
        at Object.it (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59942177/index.test.js:49:20)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
        at resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at promise.then (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.033s, estimated 10s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59942177

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. This would work great. Before I mark it as the answer, do you know of a way to perform a similar mock as you have described using the \_\_mocks\_\_ directory as described here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules.

From docs: ... you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: lodash), the mock should be placed in the \_\_mocks\_\_ directory adjacent to node_modules (unless you configured roots to point to a folder other than the project root) and will be automatically mocked. There's no need to explicitly call jest.mock('module_name').

Comment: Thanks but how would I define custom parameters for every test in this case as you have done using p.send.mockImplementation since the mock implementation for 'pushover-notifications' would be placed in another directory?